# How to encrypt data using ibm provider with certificate

Tags: java, encryption

For encrypting data using certificate we are using bouncycaste:

```
private Provider providerBC = new BouncyCastleProvider();

public byte[] encryptData(byte[] data, X509Certificate cert) throws Exception {

    CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(data);
    CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator envGen = new CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator();
    envGen.addRecipientInfoGenerator(new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(cert)
            .setProvider(providerBC));
    CMSEnvelopedData envData = envGen.generate(msg,
            new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMSAlgorithm.AES128_CBC).build());

    return envData.getEncoded();
}
```

How should I replace encrypting data using one of IBM provider ?

security.provider.1=com.ibm.crypto.pkcs11impl.provider.IBMPKCS11Impl
security.provider.2=com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE
security.provider.3=com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2
security.provider.4=com.ibm.security.jgss.IBMJGSSProvider
security.provider.5=com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPath
security.provider.6=com.ibm.security.cmskeystore.CMSProvider
security.provider.7=com.ibm.security.jgss.mech.spnego.IBMSPNEGO
security.provider.8=com.ibm.security.sasl.IBMSASL
security.provider.9=com.ibm.xml.crypto.IBMXMLCryptoProvider
security.provider.10=com.ibm.xml.enc.IBMXMLEncProvider
security.provider.11=org.apache.harmony.security.provider.PolicyProvider

because we are moving program to webpshere server where I **cant** use bouncycastle

UPDATE:

ok replace cms is probably to big problem but what about just encryption where we want to encrypt using PKCS7Padding

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding", providerBC)
```

Comment: In your code you are not only encrypting, but also using CMS to package your messages. The plain JCA API has no support for CMS, you will have to use some non-JCA API for that anyway.

Comment: and what about ibm java ? We cant use bc due to performancy on aix system